# Where do I obtain IssuerName and IssuerKey in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I am following this [tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-multi-tier-app-using-service-bus-queues/):

It mentions that I should get the IssuerName and IssuerKey from the properties of my ServiceBus.  There are no properties called IssuerName and IssuerKey when using VS2012 Server Explorer to examine my ServiceBus.  When I use the online Azure management console and I click on Connection Information I only get a Connection string not the expected IssuerName and IssuerKey.

Where are these values?  I am on the free trial, does that matter?

This is what I see.

http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Fj9_XtqozFU/VAX4tBSSBZI/AAAAAAACCcY/zpaGo5EPx9Y/w667-h519-no/Azure.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the **CONFIGURE** tab and you will see the Shared Access Policies.  For the sake of a demo/sample, you can just use the RootManageSharedAccessKey.  ***However, that is not a best practice.***  You should create shared access policies appropriate for the application, whether it be a client with Send permissions, a service with Send and Listen permissions, etc.

[image]

The sample/tutorial also has a bug in it (dated content for an older SDK).  In the QueueConnector.cs file, the CreateNamespaceManager should call the CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider instead of the CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider.

[image: *enter image description here*]

BTW, you can also get these values from your connection string.  You just have to extract them from the other values in the connection string.

Comment: Thanks.  Turns out I had got the correct  IssuerName and IssuerKey from the properties (although they have different names) but the bug in the code as described above was the problem

Comment: Just in case anyone got here from Scott Seely's Pluralsight course, the above 'bug' was also the issue for me - call the CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider instead of the CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider and you will retrieve the token just fine.

Comment: @jmdon - Thank you so much. I spent a few hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**
I checked that Microsoft Azure is moving authentication method from ACS to SAS for better performance and manageability, so removed ACS things from dialog for newly created servicebus. Seems that documentation is not yet changed.

To use with SAS, good reference is http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/ and more low-level approach is described in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn205161.aspx page.
For more information about SAS (and old ACS), please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn170478.aspx

**ORIGINAL BELOW**

Please go to Azure Portal by web browser. You may find it.

[image]

Comment: Mine doesn't look like that?. See above picture

Comment: @Richard210363 // I edit content. please check it out :)

Comment: ACS is not created anymore with Service Bus namespaces. That is why the pictures differ for namespaces created after August 2014.

Answer (score 3):

There was a change recently where the associated ACS namespace is not automatically created for a new service bus namespace created via the portal. If you need ACS authentication, you need to create the namespace either via the Management API or Azure PowerShell. I have written up some explanation of this at: http://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2014/08/27/shared-access-signatures-with-azure-service-bus/