# What is the correct format for an NServiceBus connection to an Azure Topic?

Tags: nservicebus, azureservicebus

I'm trying to subscribe to messages on an Azure topic using NServiceBus, but I'm struggling to structure my connection string.

The particular website states my connection string should look as follows:

```
Endpoint=sb://myNameSpace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedSecretIssuer=owner;SharedSecretValue=123123123123123123
```

However, I have no idea who the the 'ShadedSecretIssuer' is, and there is no 'SharedAccessKeyName' as required by Azure. This is what Azure says my connection string should look like:

```
Endpoint=sb://myNameSpace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=MY_SAS_NAME;SharedAccessKey=123123123123123123123123123=
```

If I use Azure's format though, I get the following error on startup of my NServiceBus host:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>   InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where do I obtain IssuerName and IssuerKey in Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25627356/where-do-i-obtain-issuername-and-issuerkey-in-azure)

Comment: Both formats should work just fine. Just take the value marked as 'RootManageSharedAccessKey' or equivalant in the azure portal.  PS: I'm the dev behind azure support for NServiceBus, feel free to reach out if the problem persists...